# Memory leak concerns

Tags: c++, oop, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

I find myself in a difficult situation. I have a program which is supposed to delete any memory that is dynamically allocated, but whenever I try to call the relevant methods, it comes up with a memory heap corruption.

It seems to work when I don't call the methods, but then I've probably caused a ton of memory leaks. Would anyone have any idea what is going on?

The code is below:

CSVFile.h:

```
#pragma once

class InputPattern;
class OutputPattern;

class CSVFile
{
private:
    const int NAME_MAX = 100;
    char* name;
    char** buffer;
    bool loadedFlag;
    int patternCount;
    InputPattern** inputs;
    OutputPattern** outputs;

    void setLoadedFlagTrue();
    void setLoadedFlagFalse();
public:
    CSVFile();
    ~CSVFile();
    CSVFile(const char*);

    void setName(const char*);
    char* getFilename(char*, int);

    bool getLoadedFlag();
    int loadFile();

    InputPattern* getInputPattern(int);
    OutputPattern* getOutputPattern(int);

    void addInputPattern(InputPattern*);
    void addOutputPattern(OutputPattern*);
    void deleteInputPattern();
    void deleteOutputPattern();

    void printMetaData();
    void printPatterns();
    void deleteBuffer();
};
```

CSVFile.cpp:

```
#include "CSVFile.h"
#include "InputPattern.h"
#include "OutputPattern.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void CSVFile::setLoadedFlagTrue()
{
    loadedFlag = true;
}

void CSVFile::setLoadedFlagFalse()
{
    loadedFlag = false;
}

CSVFile::CSVFile()
{
    name = NULL;
    buffer = NULL;
    inputs = NULL;
    outputs = NULL;
    patternCount = 0;

    inputs = new InputPattern*[10];
    outputs = new OutputPattern*[10];
    buffer = new char*[4];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        inputs[i] = new InputPattern();
        outputs[i] = new OutputPattern();
        buffer[i] = new char[NAME_MAX];
    }
}

CSVFile::~CSVFile()
{
    delete name;
    name = NULL;
}

CSVFile::CSVFile(const char * filename)
{
    name = NULL;
    buffer = NULL;
    inputs = NULL;
    outputs = NULL;
    patternCount = 0;

    inputs = new InputPattern*[10];
    outputs = new OutputPattern*[10];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        inputs[i] = new InputPattern();
        outputs[i] = new OutputPattern();
    }

    name = new char[NAME_MAX];
    strcpy(name, filename);
}

void CSVFile::setName(const char * filename)
{
    name = new char[NAME_MAX];
    strcpy(name, filename);
}

char* CSVFile::getFilename(char * outBuff, int outBuffSize)
{
    outBuff = new char[outBuffSize + 1];
    strncpy(outBuff, name, outBuffSize);
    return outBuff;
}

bool CSVFile::getLoadedFlag()
{
    if (name == NULL)
    {
        setLoadedFlagFalse();
        return loadedFlag;
    }

    if (patternCount == 10)
        setLoadedFlagTrue();
    else
        setLoadedFlagFalse();

    return loadedFlag;
}

int CSVFile::loadFile()
{
    FILE* f;
    if ((f = fopen(name, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("File failed to open\n");
        return 0;
    }

    for (patternCount = 0; patternCount < 4; patternCount++)
    {
        fgets(buffer[patternCount], 100, f);
    }

    patternCount = 0;
    /*ask about input interaction; potentially remove these variables afterwards*/
    float tIn, rIn, gIn, bIn, tOut, oOut;

    /*might change this to make it more flexible*/
    while (patternCount < 10)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f", &tIn, &rIn, &gIn, &bIn, &tOut, &oOut);
        printf("%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f\n", tIn, rIn, gIn, bIn, tOut, oOut);

        inputs[patternCount]->setT(tIn);
        inputs[patternCount]->setR(rIn);
        inputs[patternCount]->setG(gIn);
        inputs[patternCount]->setB(bIn);
        outputs[patternCount]->setT(tOut);
        outputs[patternCount]->setO(oOut);

        patternCount++;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return patternCount;
}

InputPattern * CSVFile::getInputPattern(int index)
{
    if (index >= 0 && index < 10)
        return inputs[index];
    else
        return 0;
}   

OutputPattern * CSVFile::getOutputPattern(int index)
{
    if (index >= 0 && index < 10)
        return outputs[index];
    else
        return 0;
}

void CSVFile::addInputPattern(InputPattern * in)
{
    inputs[patternCount] = in;
    patternCount++;
}

void CSVFile::addOutputPattern(OutputPattern * out)
{
    outputs[patternCount] = out;
    patternCount++;
}

void CSVFile::deleteInputPattern()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < patternCount; i++)
    {
        delete inputs[i];
    }

    delete inputs;
    inputs = NULL;
}

void CSVFile::deleteOutputPattern()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < patternCount; i++)
    {
        delete outputs[i];
    }

    delete outputs;
    outputs = NULL;
}

void CSVFile::printMetaData()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", buffer[i]);
    }
}

void CSVFile::printPatterns()
{
    /*to be completed*/
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < patternCount; i++)
    {
        printf("Class number %d\n", i + 1);

        printf("T in = %f\n", inputs[i]->getT());
        printf("R in = %f\n", inputs[i]->getR());
        printf("G in = %f\n", inputs[i]->getG());
        printf("B in = %f\n", inputs[i]->getB());

        printf("T out = %f\n", outputs[i]->getT());
        printf("O out = %f\n", outputs[i]->getO());
    }
}

void CSVFile::deleteBuffer()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < patternCount; i++)
    {
        delete buffer[i];
    }

    delete buffer;
    buffer = NULL;
}
```

TestHarness.cpp sample (this is executed in the main function)

```
bool TestHarness::testCSVFileSetFilepath() /*this works fine*/
{
    bool testResult = false;
    CSVFile* test = NULL;
    test = new CSVFile();
    char *testName = NULL;

    test->setName("test.txt");
    testName = test->getFilename(testName, 10);
    if (strcmp("test.txt", testName) == 0)
        testResult = true;

    delete test;
    delete testName;
    test = NULL;
    testName = NULL;
    return testResult;
}   

...........................

bool TestHarness::testCSVFileLoadFile() /*this causes the corruption*/
{
    bool testResult = false;
    CSVFile* test = NULL;
    test = new CSVFile();

    test->setName("C:/Users/user/Documents/AssignmentsSem2/ExampleFile.csv");
    if (test->loadFile() == 10)
        testResult = true;

    test->deleteInputPattern();
    test->deleteOutputPattern();
    test->deleteBuffer(); /*these three above methods are the ones I'm talking about*/
    delete test;
    test = NULL;
    return testResult;
```

}

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  Use `std::string` and `std::vector` and let them handle all of the memory management for you.

Comment: Heap corruption usually happens before you get into the deletion code. By the time you are in the deallocation code it's too late. Use a memory profiler, such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to catch them the moment they happen.

Comment: You make `4` of these: `buffer = new char*[4];` and then you allocate `10` of them in the loop.

Comment: Your have memory errors in your code because you write what is essentially C with classes, not C++, and writing C is much harder than writing C++. The main reason you're using a C++ compiler is to make such things easy. Just switching the compiler won't help you, though, you have to code to leverage all that C++ gives you. **Don't write C code when you're supposed to be using C++.** Furthermore, C++11 is old news. Learn it, use it, or lose out.

Comment: You mix array `new ...[]` with non-array `delete`; pair array `new ...[]` with array `delete[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for memory leaks with

`#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC`
`#include<crtdbg.h>`

```
struct AtExit
{
    ~AtExit()
    {
        _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    }
}doAtExit;
```

just outside the main method.

This runs whenever your program ends. All it really does is display whether you have a memory leak or not. Doesn't help with actually finding them.
You might need Visual Studio for this.
[This is how it looks when a memory leak is found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M6Wv.png)